# different versions of the same web application in the same web container

Tags: tomcat, grails, deployment

I'm trying to deploy two versions (production and test version) of the same grails web application in the same Tomcat Server

env: Grails 2.0.4, Tomcat 7

However it seems it cannot deploy both apps. I dont get any error when trying to deploy. The catalina.out just stucks during configuring Spring Security COre plugin

I have already changed the app name in application.properties file inside the .war, and of course the two .war files have different names: app_prod.war, app_test.war

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any exceptions in your other log files?  Check the localhost-<date>.log file as well.

Comment: Have you configured the applications to use different name of logs?